# canvas uses toDataURL("image/jpeg") to get a blank image

Tags: javascript, canvas, file-upload

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div>Test</div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    
        <script>
            const data =  ""//long char,base64 in github
        </script>
        <script>
            function watermarking(file, date, callback) {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = file;
                img.onload = function () {
                    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
                    let width = img.width;
                    let height = img.height;
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
    
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                    const newBase64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    callback(newBase64);
    
    
                };
    
                img.onerror = (e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                };
    
    
            }
            watermarking(data, "2022-11-11", (base64) => {
                console.log("base64 url:", base64)
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

When I use this image to get base64 url, canvas toDataURL() gets a blank image, other images get the desired effect, I don't know why.

Result from chrome log, there are many A!!!!.

From the results, it should be that the asynchronous somewhere does not take effect, resulting in toDataURL or drawImage() getting a blank image.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/qiongxing/test-canvas-base64-issue/blob/main/index.html#L17)

[image]

Comment: Debugging steps: append both the img and the canvas in the document and see which isn't rendered correctly . Your code looks fine from here, so my bet would be on the one part we don't see: the original `data` data URL. In that case the <img> would also be blank.

Comment: Wow could try that on Chrome and indeed they fail badly here. I lack time to dig properly what happens but a quick fix is to wait for the [img's `decode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) promise. I'll try to look at that tomorrow and post a proper answer when I find out what really happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something odd happening here.

First thing to note, the image that's contained in your data seems to be corrupted, at least Photoshop refuses to open it claiming that "*an unexpected end-of-file was encountered.*".
And indeed trying with any other image or even the same opened in macOS Preview app, and saved with the same settings does work fine.

So the best is to reencode your image. If it happens more often, you may want to open a new question, explaining how you are producing this image.

As for the odd part, it's that the browser is actually able to open and decode that image, but it seems that Chrome won't do this decode before being asked but still will fire the load event, and it won't wait for the image to be decoded before returning from `drawImage`. This is a bug on their part. `drawImage` is synchronous, and it's supposed to wait for the image is decoded before returning. My educated guess is that Chrome expects the decoding to already have happened when the load event fires and thus they don't check in the `drawImage` code farther than is_loaded.

Anyway, a quick workaround for that is to call the [`HTMLImageElement.decode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method, which will return a Promise resolving when the decoding is entirely done, even for this seemingly broken image.
But once again the best for you is to reencode that image.

Comment: I also forgot where the source of this picture is, it seems to be a screenshot of a mobile phone, downloaded from slack.

I used `decode()` which did solve my problem,thx.